# Get Instance dnsname from a instance create un a cloudformation autoescaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, recordset

is there any way to get the dns name of a instance created in a autoscaling group in the same cloudformation template?

The goal is:

Getdns name from the created instances.
Create a well know recordset alias to the dns instance names so everyone in the team knows it to get remote access. We dont want to use elastic-ip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation is not aware of the EC2 instances that are created by an Auto Scaling Group.

It's more common to make a [bastion](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/linux-bastion-hosts-on-the-aws-cloud-quickstart-reference-deployment/) system that is built outside of the Auto Scaling Group. Then you can have a fixed host that allows you to access all the instances within the ASG.

Comment: You can use a CloudFormation Custom Resource (Lambda) to fetch this info. The Lambda could be a simple Python script importing boto3 and doing equivalent of `aws ec2 describe-autoscaling-group ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to associate a specific DNS name to an EC2 instance, you could:

- Create an Elastic IP address
- Associate a DNS name to that Elastic IP address in Amazon Route 53
- Write a User Data script that runs when the instance starts, which associates the Elastic IP address with itself (that is, with the instance starting up)

This could be done with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws ec2 associate-address` command. See: [associate-address documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html)